# class loading error after adding application/services to zend framework site

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload, directory-structure

I'm trying to add a new folder to the application folder in zend framework, but none of the classes I create in the new folder can be found.

What I have is this structure:

```
application/
  models/
  modules/
  services/
    Test.php
```

I tried to call on the class Test.php:

```
class Service_Test{

}

$test = new Service_Test()
```

This results in the error:
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Service/Test.php' for inclusion (include_path='...') in library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146.

(The include_path contains a list of directories, which I removed for privacy).

I thought that Services would be automatically found in the same way that Models are automatically found. Does anyone know how I can make Zend framework find the Services folder?

---

I tried this as well:

```
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  => ROOT_PATH . '/application',
        'namespace' => 'Service',
    ));
```

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Service_Test' not found

Comment: Is your folder `services`? Your class is `Service_Test`; should that be `Services_Test`, or is there a typo in the directory list?

Comment: I thought services was something that was sort of standard to zend. I found the folder in zend framework references: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html . Tried 'Services' just in case, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I finally figured out what was going on. The site I am working on has an atypical setup. It's not extending any Zend Framework bootstrap class, or calling Zend_Application. The way classes were being autoloaded is by using:

```
set_include_path(ROOT_PATH . '/application/models'.PATH_SEPARATOR .
             ROOT_PATH . '/library'.PATH_SEPARATOR .
         get_include_path());

require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
@Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

I changed it to:

```
set_include_path(ROOT_PATH . '/application/models'.PATH_SEPARATOR .
             ROOT_PATH . '/library'.PATH_SEPARATOR .
         get_include_path());

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
$resources = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
          'namespace' => '',
          'basePath'  => ROOT_PATH . '/application/',
      ));
$resources->addResourceTypes(array(
          'service' => array(
              'path'      => 'services',
              'namespace' => 'Service',
          )));
```

Technically, I did not have to add the resource, but if I didn't, and just relied on putting /application/services into the include path, then I would not be able to prefix my classes with 'Service_'.

I'm not sure I would recommend this setup (no Bootstrap class extension or use of Zend_Application) for anyone else. It would be interesting to see what other people thought of this practice. Good or bad? In any case, that is how I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap

```
protected function _initNamespace(){
  Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('Service_');
```

}
Then you call call any class that starts with 'Service_'